# HTML textfield whose values cannot be 0 using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, onblur

I was trying to make a javascript function which will check if the user entered value inside a text field cannot be less than 9 digits & it cannot be all 0s.

This is what I made

```
function CheckField(field)
{
if (field.value.length <9 || field.value=="000000000")
{
alert("fail");
field.focus();
return false;
}
else 
{
return true;
}
}

<input type ="text" id="number1" onBlur='return CheckField(this)'>
```

But this doesnt check the condition where user enters more than 9 values and all 0's. It checks only for 1 condition that is with exact 9 zeros 000000000

Comment: i tryed your source, at it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understand that right you want the user to be able to enter a number with more than 9 digits, but they cannot be all zeros, right?

This can be done with a regexp:

```
var value; // Obtain it somehow

if (/^\d{9,}$/.test(value) && !/^0+$/.test(value)) {
    // ok
}
```

What this checks is whether the value is at lest 9 digits (it does not allow anything but digits) and that they are not all 0s.

Answer (score 1):

This should check for both conditions:

```
function CheckField(field){
  return !/0{9}/.test(field.value) && /\d{9}/.test(field.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var valueEntered = field.value;
if (parseInt(valueEntered) == 0) ...
```

or if you wanted to check if it was a number as well:

```
if (!(parseInt(valueEntered) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (field.value.length <9 || field.value.replace("0","") == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options spring to mind. You can try parsing the value as a number and test for `isNaN` or `!= 0`

```
  var parsed = parseInt(field.value, 10);
  if(field.value.length < 9 || !(isNaN(parsed) || parsed != 0)){
    alert("fail");
    ... rest of code
  }
```

Or you could use a `regex`

```
if(field.value.length < 9 || !/[^0]/.test(field.value){
    alert("fail");
    ... rest of code
}
```

The first option is probably quicker.